# Expired instant dry yeast

Tags: yeast

Is expired instant dry yeast dangerous to eat in breads,cakes etc.? Is it safe to eat? I have 2-1 lb. pkgs. unopened has 10/30/2010 on it,doesn't say best if or sell by, just has date. Does anyone know if it is harmful to eat? Thanks!